# Swagger UI's removes inline style, class in asp net core xml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

According this issue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6846 Swagger UI's HTML sanitizer removes inline style, class, and data-* attributes. But it can be configured by useUnsafeMarkdown=true. How to configured it in asp .net core application?

Comment: As per the documentation useUnsafeMarkdown is deprecated. You will have to find some other way.